# Max CDN link for font awsome cannot be reached

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome, cdn

I'm using icons from font awesome for my web page.

For some time i have noticed that the link has been broken or unreachable

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css

Is there some issue with their repository?

I am unable to even download static files from their web page.

http://fontawesome.io/

Comment: Can you access https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css on your browser?

Answer (score 0):

From a while even i have been getting this error in inspect element were it show connection Error Failed. If u are using icons you can try this link.

`<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/97755550d3.js"></script>`